# Triggering mousemove on the mouse's current position

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have a `<div>` with a `mousemove` handler bound to it. If the mouse pointer enters and moves around this `div`, the event is triggered.

However, I am dealing with a rich web application where `<div>`s move around the screen, appear and disappear... So it may happen that a `<div>` appears under the mouse pointer. In this case, `mousemove` is not triggered. However, I need it to be. (Note that replacing `mousemove` with `mouseover` does not change this behavior.)

Specifically, the `<div>` has to be highlighted and I deem it as a UI flaw to require the user to do a slight mouse move in order to trigger the highlighting.

Is it possible to trigger the `mousemove` event programatically? And I do not mean

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').onmousemove();
```

because `onmousemove` is parametrised by the `event` object, which I do not have.

Is it possible to make browser behave as if `onmousemove` was triggered on the current mouse's position (although in fact the mouse didn't move)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can create a `mousemove` event object to pass in, using something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("test").onmousemove = function(e) { console.log(e); };
    document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(e) { 
        var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); 
        e.initMouseEvent('mousemove',true,true,document.defaultView,<detail>,<screenX>,<screenY>,<mouseX>,<mouseY>,false,false,false,false,<button>,null);
        this.onmousemove(e); 
    };
};
```

Of course, here I'm firing it on a click, but you can do it on whatever event you want, such as when your div becomes visible, check to see if the mouse is within it. You just need to make sure your parameters are right, and you need to track the mouse position on your own. Also, there's some differences in IE, I think. Here's my source: http://chamnapchhorn.blogspot.com/2008/06/artificial-mouse-events-in-javascript.html. He added a little extra code to account for it.

Here's a fiddle to play around with. http://jsfiddle.net/grimertop90/LxT7V/1/

Comment: Yes, everything is different in IE :) I'll look into their docs for cross-browser solution. But I didn't know whether this was possible at all ;)

Comment: Just throwing this out there, while my answer here does most specifically answer the question ("Is it possible to make browser behave as if onmousemove was triggered on the current mouse's position...?"), I actually think [David Hedlund](http://stackoverflow.com/users/133802/david-hedlund)'s answer was the more elegant solution, and probably more useful for the situation you described, at least as far as you described it.

Answer (score 5):

You could modify your `mousemove` to keep a state variable with the current mouse coordinates, and use that information to perform a collision detection that you call both on mouse move, and on moving a div.

[A little example of what that might look like](http://jsfiddle.net/AKkst/)

Comment: Thank you for the nice demo :) It's a good solution, but I'll accept KenB's answer as he had the actual insight I was looking for.